# GNU Parallel not completing all "find" commands

Tags: pipe, gnu-parallel, gnu-findutils

I'm trying to parallelize a command without success, there are about 100 video files to convert.

This format resulted in 8 files being converted in a random order:

```
parallel -j 8 videoConvert ::: `find "/mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert" -iname "*.mov"`
```

This format resulted in 12 files being converted in a random order:

```
find "/mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert" -iname "*.mov" | parallel -j 8 videoConvert
```

Please Help, Thanks.

The results of:
`find "/mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert" -iname "*.mkv" | parallel --dryrun -j 8 videoConvert`

Are as follows, but I had to delete some because the website doesn't like large code blocks:

```
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/053.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/005.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/100.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/112.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/032.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/025.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/101.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/033.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/054.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/039.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/004.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/060.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/041.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/038.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/076.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/030.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/040.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/105.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/056.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/094.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/012.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/043.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/029.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/010.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/088.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/091.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/083.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/086.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/022.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/050.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/087.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/098.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/095.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/008.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/015.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/064.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/080.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/069.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/057.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/037.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/072.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/055.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/102.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/051.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/066.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/036.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/099.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/089.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/063.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/103.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/062.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/067.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/096.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/075.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/003.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/049.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/007.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/016.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/014.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/073.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/084.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/021.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/093.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/074.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/061.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/017.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/078.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/071.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/081.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/011.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/070.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/042.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/106.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/013.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/110.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/020.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/024.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/047.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/034.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/092.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/065.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/002.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/045.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/001.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/090.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/068.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/077.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/026.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/031.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/027.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/058.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/046.mkv
videoConvert /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/028.mkv
```

Comment: perhaps [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-calling-bash-functions)

Comment: Using backticks is not recommended: If some of the file names contain space, the shell will split theses, and GNU Parallel will get the wrong input. This probably explains the first issue. For the second command: please update the question with the output of `parallel --dryrun ...`.

Comment: I revised the original post to include.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: When performing these conversions I fire the batch off with nohup and close the terminal.  Could this have any interaction with parallel?

Comment: It could. Use `tmux` or `screen` instead of `nohup`.

Comment: No matter which way I send the job list to parallel it stops executing additional videoConvert commands once the terminal window is closed.  Thanks for helping me confirm the issue actually lies with an incompatibility of parallel with nohup.
I will try using tmux and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If, as your output suggests, all your files are in one directory, you can use:

```
parallel -j 8 videoConvert ::: /mnt/bulk-data-02/videos/convert/*.mkv
```

---

If your files are not in a single directory, you are generally better off piping null-terminated filenames into `parallel` like this:

```
find /mnt/... -iname ... -print0 | parallel -0 videoConvert
```